# need pointer on GeoPtProperty in app-engine/django forms

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms, geolocation

I'm not looking for a bug fix so much as an approach.  I'm a newbie with a simple model:

```
classLocation(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    geoPt = db.GeoPtProperty()
    ...
```

I use that to make a simple form:

```
class LocationForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
```

When it renders out, the GeoPt is a single text field.  For this form I'd prefer latitude and longitude fields, with validation.

Which way to go?  Is this a common problem with "complex objects" in django forms?  If so, is there an accepted solution?

Comment: Good question. GAE and we can definitely use better form handling like validation and data types beyond the trivial.

Comment: Should I suspect that the common approach is not to use a model-derived form, but instead to build one (subclass forms.Form) to suit?  Or can a model-derived form be "tweaked" adding and subtracting fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with compound types and the way database-schema derived UI has to work.

You'll be much better off dropping the deadweight and running a *specialized* form processing library, like [flatland](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flatland), [WTForm](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WTForm), [FormEncode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/FormEncode), [fungiform](http://github.com/mitsuhiko/fungiform), or indeed even a homegrown alternative.

User-input validation is not a hard problem, and it certainly doesn't always get easier by copying the database schema validation.