# Stuck coding post() for myform(forms.Form) in app engine, embedded django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I've come a ways, but have trouble pulling data from my form.  Below is my form and its post() method.  validation is working ok, but how to get 'cleaned' data in app engine's version of django?

```
def get_type(): 
    return [(str(type.key()), type.name) for type in GreType.all()] 

class LatField(forms.Field):
    def clean(self,value):
        x = None
        try:
            x = float(value)
            if x > 90.0 or x < -90.0:
                x = None
        except:
            x = None
        if x is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Latitude should be a number between 90.00 and -90.00")

class LonField(forms.Field):
    def clean(self,value):
        x = None
        try:
            x = float(value)
            if x > 180.0 or x < -180.0:
                x = None
        except:
            x = None
        if x is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Longitude should be a number between 180.00 and -180.00")

class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_type())
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), required=False)
    lat = LatField()
    lon = LonField()

class LocationHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template_data = { 'form' : LocationForm() }
    template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../template/location.html')
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_path, template_data))

  def post(self):
    data = LocationForm(data=self.request.POST)
    if data.is_valid():
        # what to do here?
        self.redirect('/locations')
```

my validation routines probably have some redundancy, but i'm not clear about python scope

I passed on a model based form ([earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743897/need-pointer-on-geoptproperty-in-app-engine-django-forms)) to get separate lat and lon fields.)

Comment: oh, "from django import newforms as forms" are the forms I'm using.

Comment: putting "myname = data.cleaned_data['name']" at "# what to do here?" yields "AttributeError: 'LocationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned data available in `self.cleaned_data`. This example worked correctly:

```
class BlogCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Blog
        exclude = ('author',)

    def clean_slug(self):
        '''Prevent duplicate blogs with equal key names'''
        # blog with given url address already exists
        if self.Meta.model.get_by_key_name(self.cleaned_data['slug']):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Blog with url '%s' already exists" %
                                         self.cleaned_data['slug'])
        return self.cleaned_data['slug']
```

Replace `return self.cleaned_data['slug']` to `return self.clean_data['slug']` if you have used builtin version of `Django`.

Try to use http://gaeframework.com - **Python** web framework designed for **Google App Engine**

Comment: When I try to access cleaned_data from my post I get "'LocationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'".  To me this means either I should use some kind of method on my LocationForm, or that the forms.Form (as opposed to forms.ModelForm) works differently(?)

Comment: You're presumably using Django 0.96, which is the default on App Engine. They changed the name from `clean_data` to `cleaned_data` in 0.97 - try using `clean_data` instead.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've figured out that I must put a method on my LocationForm to access the data.clean_data.  And of course I must return something from my clean() functions.